# Spring - java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, xml, spring

i am working on a simple spring project ; actually trying the injection through the properties file. i have to get the prop file in my applicationContext.xml file which they are not under the same directry :

> `/src
>   |_.com.luv2code.springdemo
>   |    |_sport.properties
>   |_resources
>        |_applicationContext.xml`

Trying to use this , but couldn't figure out the right classpath

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/sport.properties"/>
```

Comment: put the properties in the resources folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It should be `src/main/com.luv2code…`, not just `src/com.luv2code…`.
2. Slash denotes classpath root, but your resource seem to lay in `com.luv2code.springdemo` package.
3. Put `sport.properties` in the resources directory: `src/main/resources`.